# Retrieving Values from Form Using ASP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic

I have an html form on a page that sends information to an .asp file. In the .ASP file, I am trying to write in the javascript version of asp to retrieve the information sent by the form. What is the code for doing this? I have tried Request.Querystring, but this does not work. I want to use the javascript version as that is what I am familiar with. Please do not answer this with the VBSCRIPT version.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code? Very difficult to help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what language you use, the asp collection for form values is going to be querystring for GET and form for POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ language="Javascript" %>

<script language="Javascript" runat="server">

Response.Write("Script Engine: " + ScriptEngine() + " " +
               ScriptEngineMajorVersion() + "." +
               ScriptEngineMinorVersion() + " build " +
               ScriptEngineBuildVersion());

var p1 = Request.QueryString('p1') + '';

if (p1 != 'undefined') {
  Response.Write ("<br/><br/>you said: " + p1);
}
else {
  Response.Write ("<br/><br/>If you append a query string param called 'p1', "+
                  "it will be echoed here.");
}

</script>
```